# springmvc-router not picking routes.conf file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean wit h name 'handlerMapping' defined in ServletContext   
resource [/WEB-INF/axpense-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;

nested exception is org.resthub.web.springmvc.router.exceptions.RouteFileParsingException:
Could not read route configuration files; 

nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not open ServletContext resource [/routes.conf] at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
```

I follwed this tutorial http://resthub.github.io/springmvc-router/

Comment: Welcome on stack overflow, currently your question will not get much attention (and will like be closed). Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line `routeFiles.add("routes.conf");` with `routeFile.add(classpath:/routes.conf);`